# How to connect to Xen XAPI/XCP-NG VNC/RFB connection urls?

Tags: proxy, xen, vnc, xcp-ng

How can I connect to Xapi-style urls such as `https://192.168.1.45/console?uuid=e82eeea4-4d88-d31a-aabd-c4207ca6c24d` with a normal vnc client?

Remmina seems to straight up crash with that as the host, and trying to use a `socat` proxy also closes the connection.

KRDC and TigerVNC get confused, Vinagre gives an error, and Remmina crashes or hangs.

The [documentation](https://xapi-project.github.io/xen-api/consoles.html) shows that it's a non-standard https proxy, and I am wondering there is a Linux VNC client with this proxy support built in, or a command I can run to do the http connect directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a simple proxy in Ruby to do this. Run as `ruby thisscript.rb xapi-url yourusername`

```rb
require 'socket'
require 'base64'
require 'openssl'
require 'uri'

def connect(uri, auth)
    ss = TCPSocket.new uri.host, uri.port
    ssl_socket = if uri.scheme == "https"
        ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new()
        ssl_socket = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(ss, ssl_context)
        ssl_socket.sync_close = true
        ssl_socket.connect
        ssl_socket
    else
        ss
    end
    ssl_socket.puts("CONNECT #{uri.path}?#{uri.query} HTTP/1.1\r\nAuthorization: Basic #{Base64.encode64(auth)}\r\n\r\n")

    begin
        text = ""
        until text.include? "\r\n\r\n"
            text << ssl_socket.readpartial(1024).tap{|x|print x}
        end
        text = nil
    ensure
        puts text if text
    end
    return ssl_socket
end

listening = TCPServer.new 5903
uri = URI(ARGV[0])
username = ARGV[1]
ARGV.shift
ARGV.shift
print "Enter Password for #{username}: "
pass = gets.strip
loop do
    clent = listening.accept
    puts "Connecting..."
    ssl_socket = connect(uri, "#{username}:#{pass}")
    
    Thread.new do 
        # XEN -> VNC
        begin 
            loop do
                clent.write ssl_socket.readpartial(4096)
            end
        rescue EOFError
            client.close rescue nil
            ssl_socket.close rescue nil
        end
    end 
    # VNC -> XEN
    begin 
        loop do
            ssl_socket.write clent.readpartial(4096)
        end
    rescue EOFError
        client.close rescue nil
        ssl_socket.close rescue nil
    end
    puts "Closed stream"
end
```